# C#, how do I close my app by pressing the "Enter" button?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and was wondering, if I wanted to close my app by pressing the Enter button how would I do so? After doing some research on this website the closest thing I found to doing the trick is this code,

```
  string key = Console.ReadKey().ToString();
  if (key == "")
  {
      Console.WriteLine("User pressed enter!");
      return;
  }
```

However, this doesn't do what I want it to. For this, if I press Enter it just takes to to the "press any button to close this app". If anyone could help that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is your application a *Console Application*?  Or is it a *Windows Forms Application*?

For a **Console Application**, which by default closes automatically at the conclusion of execution, we would need to *prevent* the application from closing *until* the user presses the **Enter** key.  This can be done easily using the following code:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
do { keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true); }
while (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
```

For a **Windows Forms Application**, a different approach is required.  We would need to intercept the **Enter** key when the user presses it and close the form, which will exit the application if it is the main form.  We can accomplish via the `KeyUp()` event of the form:

```
private void MainForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

The event handler can be added from the designer, or from code using the following statement:

```
this.KeyUp += MainForm_KeyUp;
```

Finally, in order listen to key events regardless of what control on the form has focus, we need to set the `KeyPreview` property of the form to `true`, which can be done within the designer, or in code as follows:

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Set KeyPreview property to listen for key events:
    this.KeyPreview = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases it's enough to place `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of the `Main` method:

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {
     // your code here    

     Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume it is a console application.

This is the way I do it:

> Use a 'while'-loop and break when wanting to stop

Explained with some code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter) break;
        else Console.WriteLine("You gave something else");

        Console.WriteLine("This is the end of the app");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend. The answer is a simple modification to your if statement of ConsoleKey.Enter as seen here:

```
public static void Main()
{
  DateTime dat = DateTime.Now;
  Console.WriteLine("The time: {0:d} at {0:t}", dat);
  TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
  Console.WriteLine("The time zone: {0}\n", 
                    tz.IsDaylightSavingTime(dat) ?
                       tz.DaylightName : tz.StandardName);
  Console.Write("Press <Enter> to exit... ");
  while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) {} // <-- check for enter key
}
```

Original information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)